# Generic friend operator== overload

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, friend

I am currently stuck on a problem that I can't solve. I am a beginner in the world of c++.

For a homework, I have to create a generic class to represent a fraction like 5/6 or 11/4. This class is generic which allows to determine the type of the nominator and numerator (unsigned short, unsigned, unsigned long).

The goal is to be able to add, subtract, multiply, divide and compare fractions. In a first phase, I created a class and operator overloads allowing me to do everything that is required but only for instances of the class with the same type.

Now I would like to improve the existing code to be able to perform operations between fractions of different types like for example: `Frac<unsigned> == Frac<unsigned short>`. But there is something I don't understand in the syntax of overloading operators.

Let's take the == operator as an example:

```
template <typename T>
bool operator==(const Frac<T>& lhs, const Frac<T>& rhs) {
  return (lhs.numerator == rhs.numerator && lhs.denominator == rhs.denominator);
}

template <typename T>
class Frac {

friend bool operator== <>(const Frac& lhs, const Frac& rhs);

private:
    T numerator, denominator;

};
```

this is the current version that worked for the Fracs of the same type. But now I would like it to work for Fracs of a different type:

```
template <typename T>
class Frac;

template <typename T, typename U>
bool operator==(const Frac<T>& lhs, const Frac<U>& rhs){
return (lhs.numerator == rhs.numerator && lhs.denominator == rhs.denominator)
}

template <typename T>
class Frac {

friend bool operator== <>(const Frac& lhs, const Frac& rhs);


private:
    T numerator, denominator;

};
```

But I have a compilation error when I want to compare Frac of different types... I don't understand and didn't find any solution explaining concretely what the problem was and how to implement this kind of solution properly.

Could you help me please ?

I hope my question is clear and complete.

Comment: I would warn that normally you would not want this to happen. It may sound like a grand idea, but I can think of a bunch of corner cases that I would to validate (and then I would worry about all the corner cases I had missed). I would say it is best to only compare objects of the same type and force the user to convert objects to the same type before comparison.

Comment: Thank you for your advise, it's only for a scholar project. The objectives are to understand genericity and basis of class. But i keep it in mind for next time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this the following way:

```
template <typename T>
class Frac {

//friend declaration
template <typename S, typename U> friend
bool operator==(const Frac<S>& lhs, const Frac<U>& rhs);


private:
    T numerator, denominator;

};
template <typename T, typename U>
bool operator==(const Frac<T>& lhs, const Frac<U>& rhs){
return ((lhs.numerator == rhs.numerator) && (lhs.denominator == rhs.denominator));
}
```

Now you will be able to compare `Frac` for different types as you want.

Answer (score 0):

I kept running into problems when I tried to implement the operator+. The compiler told me that it was impossible to access a private field when I tried to add two Frac of different type.

In order to solve this problem, I made my class friendly with itself so that all instances of Frac can access the private fields of the other instances even if the type is different. Is this a correct solution?

```
template <typename T>
class Frac {

//make Frac self-friend to make all instance of Frac friends each others
// not depending of Frac T type
template<typename U>
friend class Frac;

friend std::ostream& operator<< <T>(std::ostream& o, const Frac& rhs);

friend Frac operator+ <>(Frac lhs, const Frac& rhs);
```